# Use access 2013 macro to show all records in web database

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, macros, ms-access-web-app

I  created a search box on an access 2013 web form to search records. Once I search/filter the record, I have a button to clear/show all records. I am having trouble using a web macro to show all the records. How do I remove the filter using a macro?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. the macro should be
setfilter
  where condition "FALSE"
  control name  datasheet

this resets the filter to false, allowing you to view all of the records.